Foundations of Galois theory
I've started to learn Galois and by me came up a question, that i couldn't nor answer on my own, either find somewhere.
Let $L$ be splitting field of some polynomial $P(x)$ over $K$. Is it always true, that $K$ cannot be obtained as set of all fixed points of some proper subgroup of $Aut(L/K)$?
And if no, maybe you know some conditions on $P(x)$, weaker than separability, when it's true?

Are you familiar with the main theorem of Galois theory? And that it fails for non-separable extensions? What is your background?

I'm just starting learn Galois theory. I'm Familiar with main theorem of it and my question in motivated namely by the one is there always nontrivial tower $K\subset  F\subset L$ when $Aut(L/K)$ has proper subgroup

Which of the fields is known to be finite? Just trying to figure out the motivation for that tag :-)

My initial problem was with $K=\mathbb{F}_p(P)$ and $L=\mathbb{F}_p(x)$

Грамматическое замечание:  у меня возник ---> I had вместо того, чтобы сказать by me came up.

@JyrkiLahtonen I am sure that the "finite fields" tag was (mistakenly) chosen because this is a question about field extensions with finite degree. After all, we speak about them as "finite extensions" even though the fields themselves need not be finite.

@KCd If I had a dime for every time I have fixed this exact instance of mistagging.... I wouldn't be rich, but I would have one more beer. In other words, yours is the most likely explanation, but I wanted the OP to comment.

To have $K$ be the fixed points of a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(L/K)$, that subgroup is ${\rm Aut}(L/K)$ and $L/K$ is a Galois extension.
Note I don't need to assume $L$ is the splitting field of a polynomial in $K[x]$; that it has to be such a splitting field is part of the conclusion.
To explain this, when $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of a field $F$ its fixed set
$$
F^G := \{\alpha \in F : \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha \ {\rm for \ all } \ \sigma \in G\}
$$
is a subfield and there is a theorem of Emil Artin that says the field extension $F/F^G$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$ (in particular, $F/F^G$ is separable and $[F:F^G] = |G|$).
When $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields, ${\rm Aut}(L/K)$ is a finite group and it turns out that $|{\rm Aut}(L/K)|$ divides $[L:K]$: see Corollary 4.2 here. If there is a subgroup $H$ of ${\rm Aut}(L/K)$ such that $K = L^H$ then by Artin's theorem $|H| = [L:L^H] = [L:K]$, so $|{\rm Aut}(L/K)|$ divides $|H|$. Also $|H|$ divides $|{\rm Aut}(L/K)|$ by Lagrange's theorem, so $H = {\rm Aut}(L/K)$. Thus $|{\rm Aut}(L/K)| = [L:K]$, which is one the conditions equivalent to $L/K$ being a Galois extension: see Theorem 4.1 here.
